# Regular expression for DDD:HH:MM format in SQL

Tags: sql, regex

I want a regular expression in `DDD:HH:MM` format in SQL with validation such as:

```
Days(DDD) - 364      
Hours(HH) – 23     
Minutes(MM) – 59
```

Can anyone please help?

I have tried this pattern:

```
^\d{2}:([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d):([0-5]\d)$
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Please explain the "not working" part ..... (sigh)

Comment: Also tags are incorrect, `mysql` and `sql-server` are two COMPLETLY different products, only use the one you are using!

Comment: Please read: [After you post, don't run away too fast—leave the question open in your browser for a bit to see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Respond%20to%20feedback%20after%20posting)

Comment: You may well find that it is better to store the time span in seconds as an integer in the database and use the user interface part of the program to take care of the conversion to and from human-readable strings.

Comment: If you have formatted dates in the DB, you're doing it **wrong**. That's a **broken** schema. The basic date and datetime types have a binary format this is **not human readable**, and you really should be using that for dates. It's more efficient, lets the DB do better data validation, indexes better, works with the built-in date functions and operations, and is less error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex has excessive group (I assume place where you've taken it checked for seconds too).

To check for described format you can use:

```
^(3(6[0-5]|[0-5]\d)|[1-2]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d?):([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

or, if you dbms doesn't support `\d`:

```
^(3(6[0-5]|[0-5][0-9])|[1-2][0-9]{1,2}|[1-9][0-9]?):([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

Explanation (for shorter version):

- `^` beginning, `$` ending of string. They check that string as a whole matched to regex,
- `3(6[0-5]|[0-5]\d)|[1-2]\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d?)` checks number of days, between `1` and `365` (incl, for leap years),
- `:` (here and after) matches literally colon,
- `([0-1]\d|2[0-3])` matches number of hours between `00` and `23` (incl), leading `0` is required,
- `([0-5]\d)` matches numbers between `00` and `59` (incl), leading `0` is required.